# How can I turn a list of form responses into a summary table?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google form that students each record attendance each weekday. the results go into a spreadsheet with a column for the students name and a column for the date.
I want to be able to look back over the past 14 days and see who did and didn't attend each day. Having it all in one table will allow me to see all the info in one glance and look for trends. This table will then be turned into a PDF and attached to an email but that part I think I found solutions for.
I can create a table frame of the dates as columns and the names as rows but I can't figure out how to evaluate if a student has an entry for that specific date.

Here's a sample sheet with a list of names, form responses and the framework of the table (I deleted my failed attempt at a formula from within the table.).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bu5j4fdzl9jUs5u-k8x7HtrDtfVJ3YFdhcrj10S9gok/edit?usp=sharing

Data
[image]

Result table
[image]

Comment: Please share a link to this example sheet, being sure to set the share permission to "Anyone with the link can edit." It is the most straightforward and foolproof way to share solutions with you.

Comment: @ErikTyler - Thanks for the comment. Added it to the question. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bu5j4fdzl9jUs5u-k8x7HtrDtfVJ3YFdhcrj10S9gok/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have placed the following array formula into cell B2 of "Two Week":

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B1:O1,'Form Responses'!B2:B&'Form Responses'!C2:C,1,FALSE))),"Y","")))
```

It "runs" the entire grid. Understand that with the power of an array formula comes one caveat: the array formula "owns" the range it "runs." So you can't manually type anything in differently. If you do, you will break the array and simply get an ERROR in cell B2 with all other results but the one you typed erased.

The first part of this formula checks to see if there is a name in Column A. If there is not, a value of null will be assigned to each cell. If there is, then the IF clause takes over.

A2:A&B1:O1 means, in English, "Make every match of every name in Column A to every date across the top." Behind the scenes, these combo name-date values temporarily fill the entire name-date grid.

Then the VLOOKUP looks at each of the temporary values and tries to match them against the combination of name and date from the 'Form Responses' sheet (i.e., B2:B&C2:C). Since these two columns are concatenated into one value per row, there is only one column — hence the 1 in the VLOOKUP. And FALSE basically means, in English, "Don't look for approximate values, only exact matches."

The IF clause wrapping the VLOOKUP checks to see if a VLOOKUP for the name-date combo is not an error [i.e., NOT(ISERROR...))]. This would mean that the name-date combo *was found* (i.e., the student was present on that date), in which case that cell in the grid will get a "Y" assigned. If the VLOOKUP does *not* find the name-date combo, then the value is set to null.

Comment: Holy crow Erik! An answer and an extremely clearly worded explanation! I'm on mobile now but will sit down and go though this carefully because I have a lot to learn from your answer. Thank you.

Comment: If this addresses the question you posted, please mark the answer as "Best Answer." It signals to other contributors/experts that this issue is now resolved. Thanks.